# How to write an external binding file for xjc?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xjc

The documentation of JAXB [xjc](http://java.sun.com/webservices/docs/1.6/jaxb/xjc.html) says:

> -b 
>       Specify one or more external binding files to process. (Each binding file must have it's own "-b" switch.) The syntax of the external binding files is extremely flexible. You may have a single binding file that contains customizations for multiple schemas or you can break the customizations into multiple bindings files:
>
> ```
>    xjc schema1.xsd schema2.xsd schema3.xsd -b bindings123.xjb
>
>    xjc schema1.xsd schema2.xsd schema3.xsd 
>          -b bindings1.xjb -b bindings2.xjb -b bindings3.xjb
> ```
>
> In addition, the ordering of the schema files and binding files on the command line does not matter.

But where do I find a documentation of this "external binding file"?

Comment: Did you look here: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbbf.html  ? The CSS of that page is dreadful and you cannot distinguish the headers from subheaders. This tutorial is available as PDF too with better typesetting. Also please see this page: http://archive.oreilly.com/pub/a/onjava/2003/12/10/jaxb.html?page=2
Hope some of it helps.

Answer (score 9):

The external binding file is documented on the [Customizing JAXB Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.6/tutorial/doc/JAXBUsing4.html) page on oracle.com

Quote:

> External Binding Customization Files
>
> Customizations to JAXB bindings made by means of an external file containing binding declarations take the general form shown below.
>
> ```
> <jxb:bindings schemaLocation = "xs:anyURI">
>    <jxb:bindings node = "xs:string">*
>       <binding declaration>
>    <jxb:bindings>
> </jxb:bindings>
> ```
>
> schemaLocation is a URI reference to the remote schema
>   node is an XPath 1.0 expression that identifies the schema node within schemaLocation to which the given binding declaration is associated.
>   For example, the first schemaLocation/node declaration in a JAXB binding declarations file specifies the schema name and the root schema node:
>
> ```
> <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="po.xsd" node="/xs:schema">
> ```
>
> A subsequent schemaLocation/node declaration, say for a simpleType element named ZipCodeType in the above schema, would take the form:
>
> ```
> <jxb:bindings node="//xs:simpleType[@name='ZipCodeType']">
> ```

See also; the [JAXB Compiler Options](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.6/tutorial/doc/JAXBUsing2.html#wp87998)

---

Another good resource for information on the external binding file is [oreilly](http://archive.oreilly.com/pub/a/onjava/2003/12/10/jaxb.html?page=2). An example binding file from [oreilly](http://archive.oreilly.com/pub/a/onjava/2003/12/10/jaxb.html?page=2) is:

Quote:

> Listing 11. Using An External Binding File
>
> ```
> <jxb:bindings version="1.0" 
>   xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" 
>   xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
>   xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc" 
>   jxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc">
>     <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="po4.xsd" node="/xs:schema">
>         <jxb:globalBindings>
>             <xjc:superClass name="com.syh.Shape"/>
>             <xjc:serializable uid="12343"/>
>         </jxb:globalBindings>
>         <jxb:bindings node="//xs:element[@name='Widgets']//xs:complexType//xs:choice">
>             <jxb:property name="Shapes"/>
>         </jxb:bindings>
>     </jxb:bindings>
> </jxb:bindings>
> ```